# Expire callback in ReCaptchaModule in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, recaptcha

I have used `reCaptcha` in `jQuery` there was way to get events as soon as captcha `checked` and as soon as `captcha` gets expired. Now i am using Angular 4 and using `import { ReCaptchaModule } from 'angular2-recaptcha';`
 .There is also way get event when captcha is checked .

```
handleCorrectCaptcha(evt) {
if (evt != null || typeof evt !== typeof undefined) {
  this.captchaChecked = true;
  this.captchCode = this.captcha.getResponse();
} else {
  this.captchaChecked = false;
}
console.log(this.captchaChecked);
}
```

where `captcha` is `@ViewChild(ReCaptchaComponent) captcha: ReCaptchaComponent;`. Now i am looking for similar kind of event when captcha gets expired. similar to those `data-expired-callback="recaptchaExpiryHeader"` in jquery provides.

Comment: What does this have to do with `angularjs` pretty sure it's only an `angular` question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve so by using call back function .To catch the expiry callback, you will need to subscribe to the `handleCaptchaExpiry` event.

```
 handleCaptchaExpiry(){
  //   doWhatEver U want.
}
```

And use `(captchaExpired)="handleCaptchaExpiry()"` inside your element.
`angular2-recaptcha` provides way get the event `handleCaptchaExpiry` is triggered when the displayed image has expired. It does not have any event parameters.